# Can u explain the working of this program of c related to headers and macro statements

Tags: c, header, header-files

Please explain the working of the program, how is the function call is going on and what's the use of #var(how it works).

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#define getName(var) #var 

int main() 
{ 

    printf("%s", getName( char )); 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What do you get when you compile it? Did you even compile it?

Answer (score 3):

`#` is an operator in preprocessing macro replacement that converts a parameter to a string literal.

So, when `getName` is invoked with the argument `char`, `#var` is replaced with a string literal containing the tokens for `var`, which is just the single token `char`. So the replacement is the string literal `"char"`.

The result in the `printf` statement is `printf("%s", "char");`, which prints “char”.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile it with `-E` compile option using `gcc` the answer is quite obvious. Below is the preprocessed program:

```
int main()
{

    printf("%s", "char");
    return 0;
}
```

As you can see the `#` macro makes a C string literal from the parameter.

Here you have another example

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define result(expr) printf("%s = %d\n", #expr, expr)

int main() 
{ 

    result(5+5);
    return 0; 
}
```

It will print

```
5+5 = 10
```

https://godbolt.org/z/Ec8T3T